# Passing arguments to a shell script to be executed within ssh

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to write a deployment script that will take the command I need to run on the remote machine and then run it on the remote machine. What I am envisioning is something as follows:

```
./DeployAndRunScript.sh "java -jar runmyjar.jar -t args &"
```

In my DeployAndRunScript.sh, the very last line is:

```
ssh -i $pemfile $targetmachine "java -jar $runcommandhere"
```

I was wondering, what would be a way to get the arguments from the commandline into the `"runcommandline"` alias and execute it within the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the arguments in a shell script you can type `$@`. Taking that a step further, you can simply change the last line to

`ssh -i $pemfile $targetmachine "$@"`

(edit: added quotes around `$@`, nice catch Barmar!)

You could replace `$@` with `$1` if you know that the command will be the first argument wrapped in quotes.

Comment: It should be `"$@"`. Putting quotes around it makes the shell re-quote everything.